# ofbiz product relationship

Tags: relationship, product, inventory, ofbiz

I purchase from a manufacturer gift cards (not virtual ones, but real plastic ones), and keep it in my warehouse as serialized inventory,  this base product is  not salable.

i sell them as another products, that has additional virtual charachteristic (fixed one, that cant be configured by the customer). e.g. i can have 3 diferent products of: 100$, 200$ and 300$, and have the style of the base product in the warehouse. again,all defined as separate product in the catalogue.

I thought of modeling the inventory product as "configurable product" and the dependant product as "configurable product instance", and add the fixed configuration as features of the product. Is this the correct way? i see configurable product example, only when customer is defining configuration (the PC001 sample). 
any other way? (maybe variant? though, my understanding it fits only when base product is virtual)
Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

For gift cards, I prefer use variant products because that's the way that use OFBiz in the demo data and, above all, OFBiz has processes ready for this type of product-with-variants: load balance of the gift card, relate gift card with customer, etc. Check [using Gift Card in OFBiz](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/FAQ+-+Tips+-+Tricks+-+Cookbook+-+HowTo#FAQ-Tips-Tricks-Cookbook-HowTo-giftcard).

Just one consideration, if you sell the gift card as a product itself, not as a "payment method", then you can use both solutions: you can create the parent product as a virtual one and its "childs" as variants (like a shirt with different sizes), or create it as a configurable one (like a PC with several PC components). Just check the different processes that uses OFBiz to "sell" the product depending of this type (variant or configurable), and use the one that suits you. In this case I also prefer use a virtual product with variants, it's easier to manage it.